# How to install Chrome or Chromium 32 bit on Ubuntu 64 bit

Tags: 64-bit, google-chrome, chromium, 32-bit

I am unable to find any advice how to install either Chrome or Chromium 32 bit on Ubuntu 64 bit 12.10. I installed ia32-libs, downloaded Chrome install package google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb and tried to install with command:

```
dpkg -i --force-architecture google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
```

...but it failed with errors:

```
# dpkg -i --force-architecture /home/stepank/Downloads/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
Selecting previously unselected package google-chrome-stable.
(Reading database ... 253612 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (from .../google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
 google-chrome-stable depends on libgconf2-4 (>= 2.27.0).
 google-chrome-stable depends on libnss3-1d (>= 3.12.3).
 google-chrome-stable depends on xdg-utils (>= 1.0.2).

dpkg: error processing google-chrome-stable (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable
```

Any advice would be helpful.

**Edit:** I forgot to mention guide I was using: https://superuser.com/questions/346775/errors-on-attempting-to-install-32-bit-chrome-in-64-bit-ubuntu

**Edit 2:** I lost my reason to install 32 bit version - memory consumption will sadly be the same. See Alvar's answer bellow.

Comment: Where did you find instructions to do so? Did you try the packages from the **Software Center**? If so, didn't they work?

Comment: Instructions to do so: [here](http://www.unixtutorial.org/2008/03/install-32-bit-deb-packages-on-64-bit/) or [here](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-a-32bit-programme-in-64bit-ubuntu/)

Software center: actually I am using Lubuntu, in Lubuntu Softtware center is no option to choose architectute. In "pure" Ubuntu 64 in **Software Center** you can force 32 bit version?

Comment: Why are you trying to install 32-bit Chrome/Chromium? Is there a specific reason? Again, did you try the **Software Center**? Sorry for insisting, but we can't help without proper information.

Comment: Reason: 32 bit Chromium consumes less RAM. Lubuntu Softtware Center does not allow to choose architecture (ie 32 bit on 64 bit system).

Comment: IMO, there isn't any mayor memory differences between either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just want to clarify **why** you are doing this. The basic idea is wrong since it will use the same amount of RAM as the 64-bit version.

32-bit consume less ram on a 32-bit system, this is a fact. But it will allocate more RAM on a 64-bit system because the 32-bit packages will be carried through the cpu as 64-bit packages and therefor allocate the same RAM as the 64-bit version. If you are worried about RAM install the 32-bit version. I just did a report on this 32/64 bit problem for school.

So my answer to you is to install any version of 64-bit or 32-bit both will use the same amount of RAM. IF you want to use less RAM install the 32-bit version or upgrade the hardware of your computer.

Comment: Thanks a lot your clarification. This sure make my attempt useless. I will either re-install 32 bit Ubuntu or live with higher memory demands.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to install chromium rather than chrome.
Chromium is available in repository for easy install, you might be interested in updating it often. To do that, you have to add chromium-update to repo.

From information i was able to obtain, the official PPA of chromium is still active but due to low human resources it's not updated always when stable version is released. For that reason some of you might still use version 18 instead of 22.

This is temporary PPA till official will work properly:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:a-v-shkop/chromium`

More info you'll find here

[www.ubuntufixer.blogspot.com](http://ubuntufixer.blogspot.com)

Comment: Thanks for you advice. Does this PPA allows me to instal **32** bit version on **64** bit Ubuntu?