# How can I install google-chrome on 32 bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome

Can I install google-chrome on my 32 bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

I have tried the commands given on [How to install Chrome or Chromium 32 bit on Ubuntu 64 bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233664/how-to-install-chrome-or-chromium-32-bit-on-ubuntu-64-bit)

I have also tried [How to install latest stable Chrome (34) on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464978/how-to-install-latest-stable-chrome-34-on-ubuntu)

But it gives error like:

```
vaibhav@vaibhav-Inspiron-1545:~$ wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.de
--2017-03-24 17:57:00--  https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.de
Resolving dl.google.com (dl.google.com)... 2404:6800:4009:805::200e, 216.58.220.174
Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|2404:6800:4009:805::200e|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-03-24 17:57:01 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Can anyone tell me how to install it?

Comment: I have noticed that you didn't correctly copy&paste the wget-command from http://askubuntu.com/questions/464978/how-to-install-latest-stable-chrome-34-on-ubuntu ->  you have missed the last `d`  from the command. That it why wget received a 404. But as @organic_marble said. the 32 bit version is unsupported and thus a security risk.

Comment: Install `chromium-browser` instead, and `adobe-flashplugin` if you really need flash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google [does not support Chrome on 32 bit Linux systems any more](http://www.pcworld.com/article/3010404/browsers/googles-killing-chrome-support-for-32-bit-linux-ubuntu-1204-and-debian-7.html).

You may be able to find an old .deb to install, but this would be a serious security risk, since it is missing months of updates, and will not receive any in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to get [Chromium](https://chromium.woolyss.com/#linux) which is an opensource chrome. They still  support 32 bit Operating systems. I'm using it right now it hasn't been updated since November though. They're still working on updates for it but a new stable version isn't available yet.